# How to print an image to specific physical dimensions on multiple pages

Tags: print-design, multiple-sizes

I have a personal project for which I have to print an image and I want it to have a printed size of 68x68cm. I only have an A4 printer. I know how to print an image on multiple pages, it's easy, but what I need is a fraction of an A4 page, not a full page.

Let me explain, how I see it in 68cm I can fit 3 x 21cm (A4 height) and I have a remainder of 5cm. Also on height I have 3 x 30 cm it is too much, I need 2 x 30cm + 8cm on the last printed page.

Anyway I hope I was clear enough.

I am a software developer, I have reasonable graphics skills (photoshop etc), but I can't seem to find a good solution, except for a custom print of a larger size, which would be quite expensive.
Thanks!

Comment: I would use illustrator! Print Tiling with Overlap!

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an solution: this website http://rasterbator.net/#
It allows you to specify an fractional output size, and therefore match exactly your needed physical size.

Comment: That service half-tones the image, therefore messing up the image.